# Performative "allow, permit, let"

Tags: causative-verbs, modality, deontic-vs-epistemic

According to Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, page 208,

> *Allow, permit, and let* can express deontic possibility, permission, but are also used more generally in a causative sense similar to
>   enable, as in *The good weather allowed us to ﬁnish the job a day
>   early*. Because of this causative meaning the time of the complement
>   situation is simultaneous with that of the modality, which is why they
>   cannot normally be used performatively: we say *I will allow him to
>   stay until tonight*, not *I allow...*

Why do they say these cannot be used performatively?

Comment: Saddening downvotes (which I've 'part-cancelled'); I think it's scandalous that people should downvote without giving a reason here, where the question is certainly at the correct level for ELU.  (a) I'm totally unsure about the **reason** given for '[the fact/assertion that] they cannot normally be used performatively' (after all, modals say are famously ambiguous on occasion). (b) "I permit you to stay until tonight" sounds acceptable if a little literary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. what about allow/let? Secondly, what's your dialect?

Comment: Non-negative etc "I allow you to stay until tonight" / "I let you stay until tonight" sound unacceptable to my ear.  //// I'm from the NW of England, by way of grammar school and a well-known university (but chemistry courses aren't all that well known for developing linguistic acumen).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Lastly, what meaning of _by way of_ have you just used? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/by_way_of

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've done the same as you. I think people object to the quotation along with *is this true?* structure of the question.  I think this has the makings of a better question, particularly about that last line ...

Comment: I could give you an answer here. However, I'm not sure if you really appreciate the answers people write for you. You've asked 64 questions and never accepted an answer (which is fine). It appears you've hardly ever even upvoted one either (less so). So, I'm wondering whether you'd really appreciate the time and effort I'd have to put in. I think I'll leave it.

Comment: @Araucaria It can be hard challenging the might of CGEL. And often questions that challenge its pronouncements are silly. I've found the odd article I think betters it. Or at least offers an equally acceptable alternative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, of course. Though sometimes all you need is a good example (like yours above).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: How about, *I hereby allow you to proceed*?

Comment: @Cerberus That's because *hereby* is itself perfomative, as I hereby inform thee.

Comment: @Araucaria: Ah, that is a fair point. So the preaedicate is performative, but the verb itself may not be. One thing: we can only make performative praedicates that way using some verbs, not all. But I suppose there are enough cases of verbs that are clearly not inherently performative which become that by adding *hereby*, as in "you are hereby a knight of the realm, congratulations!" (slightly clumsy though this sounds to me).

Comment: What does 'performative' really mean. "I made you eat the cake", "I allowed you to eat the cake" are both OK. Is the real problem hear the slightly awkward present simple "I make you east the cake", "I allow you to leave" both sound like sample sentences from an EFL text.

Comment: *I step aside and allow you to pass.* How is that not performative? In fact, how is *I will allow* not also performative, but simply in the future tense? Must something that is performative be in the present tense? I'm not sure that makes sense.

Comment: @Cerberus Obviously nothing wrong per se, but (and this is where analysis / acceptability estimates often get muddied) hardly the stuff of your everyday conversation.

Comment: @Araucaria FWIW, _I_ *appreciate the effort the effort you put into writing answers, and we're not primarily a Q & A site. Not here to serve the single querier. (*But I may disagree, on the rare occasion.)

Comment: @Mitch: *Performative* means the action is performed by saying it, not just described by saying it. So *I now pronounce you man and wife* is a performative sentence, because the civil servant has the power to change the state of affairs in the real world by his utterance: the fact that he says it makes them man and wife. If the bride's mother says, "you are now man and wife", that is not performative, but merely descriptive (assertive).

Comment: @Cerberus OK got it. But I still don't see how "I allow it" is .. um.... not allowed. Yes, "I'll allow it" is more idiomatic. It sounds funny not because it the present simple isn't performative, but because the present simple is just not that common in English.

Comment: @Mitch: I believe what you are saying is more or less what the Grammar is saying, except that they give a different reason and they phrase it in a slightly stricter manner: their *[I allow it] cannot normally be used* v. your *[I'll allow it] is more idiomatic*. Their text would admittedly benefit from additional explanation. It is less than clear now.

Comment: Performative allow or let can be found state directions **in plays** in the dialogues. For example: John: Don't bother me! (allows detective to enter the room). That is just an example.

Answer (score -1):

Enable is not performative in it of itself, so it’s synonyms aren’t either allow, permit, or let. The reason for this property of allow is allow is not a verb allowing for something is not performing something. Think about it like this you’re asking the difference between running into a door and opening it, or the difference between performing something or allowing it.

Comment: What’s wrong with this answer?